# Write a generator or return a generator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, python-internals

Inside a container class, when I want to iterate over its items (or transformations of its items, or a subset of its items), I can either *write* a generator (like `f`) or *return* a generator (like `g`):

```
class SomeContainer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = [1, 'two', 3, 'four']

    def f(self):
        for e in self.data: yield e + e

    def g(self):
        return (e + e for e in self.data)

sc = SomeContainer()
for x in sc.f(): print(x)
for x in sc.g(): print(x)
```

I do not need to pass information into the generator via `send`.

Apparently both ways behave identical (at the surface).

1. Which approach is preferable and why?
2. Which approach creates less
   overhead or has other advantages I fail to spot?

Answer (score 2):

Generator comprehensions (such as in `g()`) would be slightly faster.

Explicit loops (such as in `f()`) would probably be more readable if your logic beccomes more complex than in the simple example you provided.

Other than that, I can't think of any material differences.

But remember what they say:

> Premature optimization is the root of all evil!

Comment: Actually the generator comprehension is slower in this case. 0.634 using `f()` and 0.753 using `g()`

Comment: `g()` is equivalent to `def h(self): return self.f()` so it shouldn't be faster than mere `f()`. Though it depends on how generator expressions are implemented.